# Python: function that adds all the values in a list and prints the total

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

I m new to python and based on what I learnt so far this code should be correct,but it doesn't run.Can any of you help out

```
list_x=[4,5,6,7]

total1=0

def total(list_1):
    for values in list_1:
        total1 += values 
        
    print(total1)
    
total(list_x)
```

Comment: "but it doesn't run" What do you mean, *exacty*? What are you doing?

Comment: _it doesn't run_ If you're getting errors, please include them in the question.

Comment: `total1 += values` You can't modify global variables inside functions without the `global` keyword.

Comment: You must define the initial total in the function, not outside of it.

Comment: Just for fun, a shortcut would be: `sum(list_x)`.  I only post this comment, not to discount learning to write functions (good work!), but simply to show the possible brevity of Python.  :-)

Comment: wow you guys reply real fast. Thanks i figured out the problem now

Comment: @Sovietsperm - Welcome to SO.  Please remember to accept (and upvote when you have enough rep) those answers which help you along the way.

Comment: @S3DEV could you explain how to use sum because i tried using sum(list_x) and it gave me an error

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-e9cd25eb2545> in <module>
      1 list_x=[4,5,6,7]
      2 
----> 3 sum(list_x)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: This should not give any errors: `list_x = [4, 5, 6, 7]` then `sum(list_x)`.

Comment: @S3DEV yeah it works now. By the way is it normal for python to take up 70% of my cpu ? Im using jupyter notebook via anaconda and my cpu is relatively new.

Comment: That's a very broad question mate.  It all depends of the type of processing you have going on. Very large datasets, complex graphs in Notebook - yes, it's plausible. But for small functions such as this, no.  I'd recommend a Python close/re-open or reboot to clear the process log/caching.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `total1` variable inside your function. Right now, it is a global variable, which means that you can't modify it from within the function without declaring your reference to it as `global`.

```py
list_x=[4,5,6,7]

def total(list_1):
    total1=0
    for values in list_1:
        total1 += values 
        
    print(total1)
    
total(list_x)
```